Is it wrong if i give the two mutable interaction source to two nested components in jetpack compose?
the boxwithconstraints and its child box shares the same mutableinteractionsource.
The onNavigateBack() lambda was never called...
@Composable
fun CenterAlignedContentWithBlackOverlay(
    onNavigateBack : () -> Unit,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val wrapperInteractionSource = remember {
        MutableInteractionSource()
    }
    
    val boxInteractionSource = remember {
        MutableInteractionSource()
    }
    BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier
        .clickable(interactionSource = boxInteractionSource, indication = null) {

        }
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.5f))) {
        val width = maxWidth
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .width(width / 4)
            .align(Alignment.CenterStart)
            .blur(3.dp).clickable(interactionSource = boxInteractionSource,indication = null, onClick = {
                onNavigateBack.invoke()
            })
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(width / 2)
                .background(colors.background)
                .align(Alignment.Center)
        ) {
            content.invoke()
        }
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .width(width / 4)
            .align(Alignment.CenterStart)
            .blur(3.dp).clickable(interactionSource = boxInteractionSource,indication = null, onClick = {
                onNavigateBack.invoke()
            }))
    }
}

I've tried giving the same mutableInteractionSource but it didn't seem to work and i tried giving two different ones and still the results were same?
Can someone please point out what i am doing wrong and help me out?

What are you trying to achieve? It's not clear to me...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am trying to acheive a screen with both the sides blacked out and with content in the center and when i click on the black overlays the screen should invoke a callback.
